# PHP not saving sessions on subdomain, ok on domain: CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, subdomain

We have a CentOS 5.4 server serving a number of our websites. The server is managed by Plesk 9.2.3.
Our websites are developed in php.

We have our main domain ourapplication.co.uk in /var/www/vhosts/ourapplication.co.uk/httpdocs, and
our subdomain api.ourapplication.co.uk in /var/www/vhosts/ourapplication/subdomains/api/httpdocs

The following pages are in BOTH locations:

**davidstest1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<title>Code Blue Stats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "This is Davids Test 1. It will set SESSION['davids']='davids variable set' and then link
to davidstest2.php<br />
davidstest2 wil then do a session_start() call, and attempt to display SESSION['davids'] <br />";
$_SESSION['davids']='davids variable set';
?>
<a href="davidstest2.php">davidstest2.php</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**davidstest2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<title>Code Blue Stats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "This is Davids Test 2. It will do a session_start() call, and attempt to display SESSION['davids'] <br />";
$r=print_r($_SESSION, true);
echo "<pre>Session in <br />";
echo $r;
echo "<br /></pre>";
?>
<a href="davidstest2.php">davidstest2.php</a>
</body>
</html>
```

in the MAIN domain, davidstest2 returns

```
This is Davids Test 2. It will do a session_start() call, and attempt to display SESSION['davids'] 
Session in 
Array
(
    [siteMode] => none
    [davids] => davids variable set
) 
davidstest2.php
```

in the api SUBDOMAIN, davidstest2 returns

```
This is Davids Test 2. It will do a session_start() call, and attempt to display SESSION['davids'] 
Session in 
Array
(
)
davidstest2.php
```

Obviously, something in the Apache config or the Php config is wrong, as the session variable should be stored for both domains

```
Relevant phpinfo() reports:
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 2):

The location of the files on the server is not important. To ensure that a session cookie will be available to both a domain and its subdomains, use the php function [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and set the *domain* parameter appropriately:

> Cookie domain, for example
>   'www.php.net'. To make cookies visible
>   on all subdomains then the domain must
>   be prefixed with a dot like
>   '.php.net'.

Note that:

> you need to call
>   session_set_cookie_params() for every
>   request and before session_start() is
>   called

so your script(s) should include this, or you may choose to set the cookie domain explicitly in your php.ini file.

Comment: it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Cookies don't work across different hostnames (actually that's not strictly true, but the real answer would take me too much time to type).

If you must have multiple hostnames, then use a single sign on solution.

C.

Comment: But I'm not trying to transport session info across hosts - the're all independent sites. I just want session info to be preserved within each host. Am I being dense?

Comment: OK - read your post again more carefully. Try using wireshark / iehttpheaders (MSIE) / LiveHeaders (firefox) to ensure the cookie is being set on the browser and presented to webserver subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify the cookie domain for the session is set correctly. Run session_get_cookie_params ( void ). This will return an array with the domain where the cookie will function among other things.